# C# richTextBox spacing issue?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I am writting a client for a chat server program I wrote that uses a richTextBox control to display user text. Everything works except some ASCII art that I am using for my servers motd. When running it my text is displayed like this. As you can see there appears to be something wrong with the spacing.
[image]

Now if I type this up in notepad using the exact same font I get this. Why isn't the richTextBox displaying the same result? I am really confused here.....

[image]

Edit: The problem is due to the RTF sent by the server. How can I add an extra space in RTF?

Comment: can you share the text, would like to try out using an console application.

Comment: @user - which font r u using for RTF ?

Comment: @Yasser - its winform not console app

Comment: it does not matter what app you are making, all I wanted was the text so that I could recreate the issue and probably help you get a solution

Comment: I do not see any of the backslashes (\\) in the first image. How are you sending the text to `RichTextBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the problem originates from the way you feed the `RichTextBox` control with your ASCII art text. By examining both images, you can see that the missing characters in your `RichTextBox` are backslashes and the characters after backslashes. It seems that you forgot to escape the backslash character.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is clearly the Font, `Notepad` uses `Monospace` Font, while the RichTextBox seems to be using `Non-Monospace` font.

Since for the `Monospace` font the width of each `character` are equal, while for `Non-Monospace` the `character` width differ, Hence the Display issue.

I forgot to notice the missng `backslash` you need to escape the `\` character before appening it to the RichTextBox.